# Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: ')' at line 12 column 10

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am getting error on line 12 :

> Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: ')' at line 12 column 10

and i am not getting what system of my code is wrong ?

here is my code :

```
   String RTid = [Select Id From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'Account' and Name = 'recordtype1].Id;

     String Rtid2 = [Select Id From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'Account' and Name = 'recordtype2' ].id;

     Account a = New Account(recordTypeId=RTid,Name='test dummy account');

     Account a1 = New Account(recordtypeid=Rtid2,FirstName = 'SFDC',LastName = 'Axel');

    mycustomobject1__c m1=new mycustomobject__c(Account__c=a.id,Name='test',Active__c=true);

     mycustomobject2__c m2=new mycustomobject2__c(Name='XXXXXXX',mycustomobject1__c=m1.id,Consumer__c=a1.id);

     mycustomobject2__c m3=new mycustomobject2__c(Name='YYYYYYY',mycustomobject1__c=m1.id,Consumer__c=a1.id);

     List<mycustomobject2__c> mlist = New List<mycustomobject2__c>();
     mlist.add(m2); // this line is throwing erreor : Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: ')' at line 12 column 10
```

anyone helps appreciated!!!

Comment: There is a missing quote near the end of the first line.

Comment: are you still getting this compile error ?

Comment: yes/....i just commented that last line  and don't know its weird message

Answer (score 1):

```
String RTid = [Select Id From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'Account' and Name = 'recordtype1'].Id;
```

include this in your code at line 1

Comment: its a typo in here , my code works - and test coverage goes above 77% if i remove this line : mlist.add(m2); // this line is throwing erreor : Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: ')' at line 12 column 10, and no errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to define list with proper types....

Replace `List mlist = New List();` with `list<mycustomobject2__c> mlist = new list<mycustomobject2__c>();`

Check this document for more information on how to initialise, define and use li[List defintion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_constructors)

Comment: I have added that , still on same error.